# Garbage collection Islands of Isolated Objects

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I don't understand the meaning of "Islands of Isolated Objects"

```
class X2{  
    public X2 x; 

    public static void main(String... args){  
        X2 x2 = new  X2();  
        X2 x3 = new  X2();  
        x2.x = x3;  
        x3.x = x2;  
        x2 = new X2();  
        x3 = x2;  
        doComplexStuff();  
    }  
}
```

after line 9 runs, how many objects are elgible for garbage collection?
At first I thought none. But the answers is two. What happens for example with x2.x and x3.x? they are objects too, aren't they? To be honest I don't understand this K&B question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example you create a total of 3 objects (on lines 4, 5 and 8). I'll call them o1, o2 and o3 respectively. o1 is referenced by x2, o2 is referenced by x3. They also contain a reference to each other (o1.x=x2.x references o2, o2.x=x3.x references o1). When line 8 is executed, o1 is no longer referenced by x2, but it is still referenced by o2.x=x3.x. When line 9 is executed, o2 is no longer referenced by x3, but is still referenced by o1.x.

At this point o1 and o2 still reference each other. However there are no other references to these objects so they cannot be used. They are therefore eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

If garbage collection were based on the rule

> Has anybody got a reference to me?

Then x2 refers to x3 and x3 refers to x2, so both are being referred to, so they would not be garbage collected.

However the garbage collection rules are cleverer than that. x2 and x3 are a little "island", and once we leave the scope where they were declared no other object has a reference to them. So the whole "island" cannot be reached, so the whole island is garbage collected.